# Change <input> to <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/FYqq2/

its not working help me

```
<div id="d3">
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">Home</div>
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">About</div>
<div id="d1">
    <input type="button" value="Shrink" onclick="showLess()">
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
function showMore() {
    button.style.display="none";
    d3.style.display="block";
}

function showLess() {
    button.style.display="inline-block";
    d3.style.display="none";
}
//]]>  

</script>
```

How can I Change

`<input id="button" type="button" value="Expand" onmouseover="showMore()">`

To

`<img type="button" src="xxxxx.jpg" height="52" width="72" onmouseover="showMore()">`

should i add (id="button") in img tag?

Comment: you can set your image as background by giving class to input tag

Comment: never try to style input elements, <img type="button" is the correct solution!

Comment: you just try to remove input & then add img tag

Comment: @johnSmith i think you meant `<input type='image'`

Comment: I Want "showMore()" script to work..

Comment: Try Uploading In [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use input as image.
More info http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

it could look somethin like this:

```
<input type="image" src="xxxxx.jpg" height="52" width="72" value="Expand" onmouseover="showMore()">
```

It will act as submit button. You can use *preventDefault* or *return false* if you don't want it to submit on click.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some class which has background image set to it. Something like this:

```
.myButton {
background:url(/images/Btn.PNG) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replacewith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('#button').replaceWith('<img />',{
type: button,
src: 'xxxxx.jpg',
height: 52,
width: 72
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as `<img type="button" />` in html, but you can:

create

```
<input type="image" />
```

or create

```
<button type="button"><img src="xxxxx.jpg" /></button>
```

or use css to add background-image

```
#button {
    background: url(xxxxx.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<img id="button" src="xxx.png" width="72" height="52" onmouseover="javascript:showMore();">
```